# Sending files to a server using DJANGO

Tags: django, ftp

Im relatively new to django and would like to get my feet wet with a simple project. The goal is to gather files from a certain directory, that is specified in the front end of the website, then send it to an off shore server. The django apps in the project will be-
1) gather_files- gather files from a certain directory given a path. I will be making a list in models.py and add each file to it given the directory. 
2) send_files- takes the list and sends it to the specified server's IP address using ftp.
Im looking for structural help and pointers that can start me in the right direction. Is there a better way going about this?

Comment: not very clear what you're trying to achieve, 3 machines involved, client -> server -> 'off shore', where is the directory that gather_files take files from?

Comment: is that a simple project?

Comment: Sorry I will do my best clarifying. so its 2 machines, the client and server. Im implementing client with a website thats built in django. gather_and_send_files function (yea I changed it a bit) gets files from a directory and sends it to the server using paramiko.

Comment: I believe its a simple project, yet to run into any major roadblocks. Atleast Im already learning quite a bit.